# How to apply left join in MySQL between four tables

Tags: sql, left-join

```
SELECT * FROM
  mtc_employee_master EB,
  mtc_employee_education_master EE,
  mtc_employee_experience_master EEXP,
  mtc_employee_salary_master ES 
WHERE
  EB.id=16 AND 
  EE.emp_tbl_id=EB.id AND 
  EEXP.emp_tbl_id=EB.id AND 
  ES.emp_tbl_id=EB.id
```

This works fine if the data is available in all the tables. I want to fetch records from `mtc_employee_master` as is a master table.

I have success in joining two tables with the query below-

```
SELECT * FROM 
  mtc_employee_master EB 
LEFT JOIN 
  mtc_employee_education_master EE
ON
  EB.`id` = EE.`emp_tbl_id` 
WHERE
  EB.id=16
```

Comment: Just adding other LEFT JOIN after this one didn't work ?

Comment: Please add the tag for your DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM mtc_employee_master EB
  left join mtc_employee_education_master EE on EE.emp_tbl_id=EB.id
  left join mtc_employee_experience_master EEXP on  EEXP.emp_tbl_id=EB.id 
  left join mtc_employee_salary_master ES on ES.emp_tbl_id =EB.id
  WHERE EB.id=16
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM mtc_employee_master EB
LEFT JOIN mtc_employee_education_master EE  ON EE.`emp_tbl_id` = EB.`id`
LEFT JOIN mtc_employee_experience_master EEXP ON EEXP.`emp_tbl_id` = EB.`id`
LEFT JOIN mtc_employee_salary_master ESAL ON ESAL.`emp_tbl_id` = EB.`id` WHERE EB.`id`=16    worked...emp_tbl_id instead of id..thanks

Comment: hello..now how to take different fields of a table with same name..let's say date is common in all the four fields and I want only ES.date..??

Comment: @DevLakshman Then you have to add the table alias in front of the column name: es.date

Answer (score 0):

Do like this (**EDITED**) :

```
 SELECT EB.*
 FROM mtc_employee_master EB left join 
 (SELECT EE.id var FROM mtc_employee_education_master EE 
  join  mtc_employee_experience_master EEXP on EE.id=EEXP.id
  join mtc_employee_salary_master ES 
  on ES.id=EEXP.id) temp
  on EB.id= temp.var
 where  EB.id=16;
```

Comment: error as Erreur de syntaxe près de 'FROM mtc_employee_master EB left join 
 (SELECT EE.* FROM mtc_employee_education' à la ligne 2

Comment: sorry but error..Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
  mtc_employee_master EB,
  mtc_employee_education_master EE,
  mtc_employee_experience_master EEXP,
  mtc_employee_salary_master ES 
WHERE
  EB.id=16 AND 
  IFNULL(EE.emp_tbl_id,0)IN(EB.id,0) AND 
  IFNULL(EEXP.emp_tbl_id,0)IN(EB.id,0) AND 
  IFNULL(ES.emp_tbl_id,0)IN(EB.id,0)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: Mysql eh...see revised statement